# I'm getting an "Extra argument" error trying to use the coordinateWritingItemAtURL() method of NSFileCoordinator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The error is: Extra argument 'writingItemAtURL' in call

I'm developing in Swift for iOS
I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite
I've tried deleting the DerivedData and restarting xcode and it has not helped.

Here is some playground code to illustrate the issue:

```
let movingOption = NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForMoving
let replacingOption = NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForReplacing
var testURL1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file1")
var testURL2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file2")
var error1: NSErrorPointer?
var error2: NSErrorPointer?
let fc = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
var result = false

fc.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(testURL1, options: movingOption, writingItemAtURL: testURL2, options: replacingOption, error: &error1, byAccessor: { (newURL1: NSURL, newURL2: NSURL) in
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    result = fm.moveItemAtURL(newURL1, toURL: newURL2, error: error2)
    if !result {
        println("DEBUG: Failed to move file \(moveError?.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line with this:

```
fc.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(testURL1, options: movingOption, writingItemAtURL: testURL2, options: replacingOption, error: &error1) { (newURL1: NSURL, newURL2: NSURL) -> Void in
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    result = fm.moveItemAtURL(newURL1, toURL: newURL2, error: error2)
    if !result {
        println("DEBUG: Failed to move file \(moveError?.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
```

Comment: Using that line, the error is now "Extra argument 'options' in call"

Comment: Sorry, that error was not showing for me in the playground yesterday, but when I opened it this morning I see the same error. Argh.

Answer (score 0):

I found my silly mistake.  The URLs in the argument list need to be unwrapped, so the working code looks like this:

```
let movingOption = NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForMoving
let replacingOption = NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForReplacing
var testURL1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file1")!
var testURL2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file2")!
var error1: NSError?
var error2: NSError?
let fc = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
var result = false

fc.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(testURL1, options: movingOption, writingItemAtURL: testURL2, options: replacingOption, error: &error1, byAccessor: { (newURL1: NSURL!, newURL2: NSURL!) in
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    result = fm.moveItemAtURL(newURL1, toURL: newURL2, error: &error2)
    if !result {
        println("DEBUG: Failed to move file \(error2?.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```